# Order of coefficients in complex contrast

Tags: r, anova, compare-contrast

In my data, the output variable is chicken weight and the independent variable - Feed, has six different factors: casein, horsebean, linseed, meatball, soybean, sunflower. I make the Feed variable as factor with the code in R below:

```
levels(chickwts$feed)
chickwts$feed <- factor(chickwts$feed, labels = c('casein',
                                                   'horsebean',
                                                   'linseed',
                                                   'meatmeal',
                                                   'soybean',
                                                   'sunflower'))
```

I want to do a contrast between the average of the bean feeds (horsebean and soybean feeds) and the average of the seed feeds (linseed and sunflower feeds). From my understanding, the coefficient should be c(0, .5, -.5, 0, .5, -5), which follows the label order in the above code.

Then I will use the `library(emmeans)` to conduct analysis.

```
c.weights1 <- c(0, .5, -.5, 0, .5, -5)
emmeans.output1 <- emmeans(anova_result,'feed',contr=list('horesbean and soybean vs linseed and sunflower'=c.weights1))
emmeans.output1
```

Is it correct? I’m not sure about the order of coefficients and what determines the order of coefficients. Does it follow the order that I created in the

```
chickwts$feed <- factor(chickwts$feed, labels = c('casein',
                                                   'horsebean',
                                                   'linseed',
                                                   'meatmeal',
                                                   'soybean',
                                                   'sunflower'))
```

Comment: Looks correct. The default ordering of factors is the lexical order of the labels. Which happens to also be the order that you specified.

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks. So it means that if I didn't specify the order of labels, R would automatically order the factors and coefficients according to the alphabetical order. Is it correct?

Comment: That’s correct.